# URL for database on Appfog

Tags: appfog

I would like to execute a query on a database on appfog but I don't know the URL for it but I was given the passoword and username, your insight is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your database using your preferred method of the language you're using. See https://docs.appfog.com/services/mysql for more information (assuming it's a MySQL database).

The username, password, and host, are all in a "credentials" parameter, which is part of the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. The page linked tells you how to access that variable in various languages.

Comment: Thanks Anotonio for the reply I tried connecting using it but testing for connection doesn't work as I was trying to manipulate the database using work-bench, so the connection failed even when I have the fields such as mthe host name, username, password and others but I am not sure why it doesn;t connect, though I check with both the 10000 port and the 3306 port